# Como trabalhar com valores super precisos em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, float

Estou criando um algoritmo e estou deparando com um problema estranho, eu tenho um conjunto de valores precisos e um objetivo desconhecido, basicamente uma rede neural. Eu usei diversas táticas para otimizar os pesos e agora fiz um algorítimo para tentar achar os melhores valores na força bruta. O algorítimo transforma o valor de um único peso em string e vai alterando um valor individual dessa string, desta forma:

0.99227**8**8982003661
 0.99227**9**8982003661
 0.992272**0**982003661
 ***0.992272***1**98200366**
 0.992272**2**982003661
 0.992272**3**982003661
 0.992272**4**982003661
 0.992272**5**982003661
 0.992272**6**982003661
 0.992272**7**982003661

Cada vez que isso acontece, eu converto a string para float e executo a rede neural, capturando a precisão da rede com os pesos, porém, como vemos na linha marcada, o número 1 no final foi suprimido sem causa alguma, aparentemente existe um bug na função "float" que pode ou não sumir com o ultimo valor quando se trata dessa precisão.

Fiz esse teste para demonstrar a anomalia, primeiro a string e depois o valor convertido:

strin 0.992272898200**1**661
float 0.992272898200**1**661

strin 0.992272898200**2**661
float 0.992272898200**2**661

strin 0.992272898200**3**661
float 0.992272898200**3**661

strin 0.992272898200**4**661
**float 0.992272898200**4**66**

strin 0.992272898200**5**661
float 0.992272898200**5**661

Quando eu trabalho com baixa precisão, esse problema não aparece:

strin 1.023
float 1.023

strin 1.123
float 1.123

strin 1.223
float 1.223

strin 1.323
float 1.323

strin 1.423
float 1.423

strin 1.523
float 1.523

strin 1.623
float 1.623

strin 1.723
float 1.723

strin 1.823
float 1.823

strin 1.923
float 1.923

strin 1.103
float 1.103

strin 1.113
float 1.113

strin 1.123
float 1.123

strin 1.133
float 1.133

strin 1.143
float 1.143

strin 1.153
float 1.153

strin 1.163
float 1.163

strin 1.173
float 1.173

strin 1.183
float 1.183

strin 1.193
float 1.193

strin 1.120
float 1.12

strin 1.121
float 1.121

strin 1.122
float 1.122

strin 1.123
float 1.123

strin 1.124
float 1.124

strin 1.125
float 1.125

strin 1.126
float 1.126

strin 1.127
float 1.127

strin 1.128
float 1.128

strin 1.129
float 1.129

A única diferença entre os valores é o float.

```
for valor in range(0,10):

    listaCaracteres = listaCaracteres[:nchar] + str(valor) + listaCaracteres[nchar + 1:]
    finalCaracteres = decimal + '.' + listaCaracteres

    print('strin',finalCaracteres)
    print('float',float(finalCaracteres))
```

Infelizmente, isso está atrapalhando muito o funcionamento do algoritmo, vocês tem alguma ideia de como manter a precisão convertendo a string para float sem este "bug"? (Avisando que o valor vem em float, é convertido para string, sofre a alteração e é convertido para float novamente, sendo que esse problema sempre acontece no ultimo caractere, apenas quando eu trabalho com essa precisão, testes com 4 casas por exemplo, tudo acontece corretamente )

Estou usando o Ubuntu 19.10 com essa versão do Python:
3.7.5 (default, Nov 20 2019, 09:21:52) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20191008]

Comment: talvez usando a classe Decimal que esta no modulo decimal possa resolver esse problema

Comment: Ual, essa biblioteca é fantástica, resolveu meu problema, muito obrigado @EltonNunes

Comment: O work-around pra isso em Python é usar decimal.Decimal - mas se isso é sua profissão DEFINITIVAMENTE você precisa entender sobre números de ponto flutuante e como são tratados pelo harware - sugiro começar por aqui: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: PS. o Decimal em Python pode trabalhar com uma precisã arbitrária pré-selecionada, mas isso é centenas de vezes mais lento do que trabalhar com os núemros de ponto flutante de hardware - que tem o limite acima (E isso não é algo específico do Python, acotnece em qualquer linguagem) - então tem que visitar seu problema e ver se ele tem como ser computado com  numeros pontof lutuante com perda, ou emulado com inteiros- ou, se dependendo do caso, usar decimais arbirtrários mesmo com a lentidão que eles tem.

Comment: O link acima acho que fica acadêmico demais - e muito matemático - acho que esse artigo é mais tranquilo de começar: https://www.phys.uconn.edu/~rozman/Courses/P2200_15F/downloads/floating-point-guide-2015-10-15.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Como o computador tem só trabalha com operações binarias os valores que decimais possui uma certa precisão maxima depois de certo ponto o valor é arbritario do valor mais proximo que a operação binaria conseguiu realizar.

Uma saida é você transformar todos os numeros em inteiros e trabalhar com eles
e depois formatar eles para o ponto flutuante novamente

Exemplo Pseudo Código

```
#Considerando um numero com 11 casas decimais
x = 0.12390128390
print(x)
#>> 0.1239012839
#Transformo em inteiro
conv_x  = x*(10**11)
conv_x
print(conv_x)
# >> 12390128390.0
#Faço alguma operação lembrando que devem manter a mesma base
operacao = conv_x + (0.00001*(10**11))
print(operacao)
# >> 12391128390.0

#diferença
print(operacao - conv_x)
#>> 1000000.0

#Reconverto para a ponto flutuante
ponto_flutuante = operacao * (10**-11)
print(ponto_flutuante)
#>> 0.12391128389999999

#note que o valor ja foi arredondado neste caso o ideal é salvar 
# o valor multiplicado por um expoente X e se necessario converter novamente
# salve o resultado como texto para não acontecer arredondamentos

ponto_flu_str =  "0." + str(int(operacao))
print(ponto_flu_str)
#>> 0.12391128390
```